# Priniting Exception

Tags: java, exception, jasper-reports

I am developing a software using *Java*.

I linked a *JasperReports* with a bar-code access for the bill printing.

My problem is, when I attempting print that report, this  exception is occurred:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: java.io.IOException: SAX2 driver class org.apache.crimson.parser.XMLReaderImpl not found
    at net.sf.jasperreports.renderers.BatikRenderer.ensureSvg(BatikRenderer.java:198)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.renderers.BatikRenderer.getDimension(BatikRenderer.java:142)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.draw.ImageDrawer.draw(ImageDrawer.java:110)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.draw.PrintDrawVisitor.visit(PrintDrawVisitor.java:117)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.draw.PrintDrawVisitor.visit(PrintDrawVisitor.java:55)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRTemplatePrintImage.accept(JRTemplatePrintImage.java:393)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.draw.FrameDrawer.draw(FrameDrawer.java:231)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.draw.FrameDrawer.draw(FrameDrawer.java:179)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRGraphics2DExporter.exportPage(JRGraphics2DExporter.java:259)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRGraphics2DExporter.exportReportToGraphics2D(JRGraphics2DExporter.java:232)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRGraphics2DExporter.exportReport(JRGraphics2DExporter.java:171)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPrintServiceExporter.print(JRPrintServiceExporter.java:325)
    at sun.print.RasterPrinterJob.printPage(RasterPrinterJob.java:1968)
    at sun.print.RasterPrinterJob.print(RasterPrinterJob.java:1457)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPrintServiceExporter.exportReport(JRPrintServiceExporter.java:286)
    at Server.Print.Url.Print.printReport(Print.java:62)
    at Server.Print.Url.Print.createReports(Print.java:116)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: And i sure this a problem with a jar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application isn't finding a required library. From what I see, you'll need to download [Apache's Crimson XML Parser](http://xml.apache.org/crimson/) and add it to your application's classpath.

Comment: the problem of missing a lib file.

Comment: Do you have the lib file? Have you tried adding it to the classpath? Are you using an IDE? Without more information it's hard to help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the library is not on your classpath

If you are running on the command line either

1. Update your manifest to include the jar in its classpath
2. Manually include using '-cp' in your line to add more classmate entries. Eg java -co jar1.jar;jar2.jar -jar my.jar   This assumes Windows as the separator is ;